# For Loop - Survival Analysis

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I'm trying to run a survival analysis for hundreds of genes within a specific cancer type.  I have 2 data frames (m2 and m3).  m2 includes the sample ID as well as a column for Overall survival (how long the sample has been alive for) and status (if the sample is alive or deceased).  In m3, I have one column for sample ID and columns 2:256 are different genes.  If each sample has a mutation in this gene it was denoted by 1, if not, it was denoted by 0.  I am trying to determine which genes are statistically significant when comparing their role in survival.  I am trying to run a for loop to run this survdiff function and generate p-values, but keep getting an error.

```
for (x in 2:ncol(m3)) {survdiff(Surv(m2$Overall.Survival, m2$Status) ~ x, data = m3)}
```

The error I keep getting is:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = Surv(m2$Overall.Survival, m2$Status) ~  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'x')
```

Comment: The error seems clear, what do `nrow(m2)` and `nrow(m3)` return?

Comment: I was hoping to return a survdiff p-value for each column (gene) for columns 2:256 (all genes that I have included).

Comment: Okay, but what does that have to do with the error or my question?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I know the answer.  I thought my code would give the output of the survdiff function for columns 2 - 256.  Am I wrong about this?

Comment: You are not hearing me, Matt. All I asked was for you to return two numbers: the number of rows in each of your two data.frames. What is there to know? Looking at [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48726437/survdiff-p-value-comparison), though, I wonder: are you intentionally mixing data.frames here? Try `survdiff(Surv(m2$Overall.Survival, m2$Status) ~ x, data = m2)` (changing the last `m3` to `m2`). But, just like your previous question, since you provide no sample data, there is nothing for us to go on.

Comment: You’re trying to iterate a function across columns using a for loop. You need to use `lapply`

Comment: Matt - how many columns does m2 have? If you want to process all rows... then you need for (x in 2:nrow) im guess you dont want col 1, as its likely an id or date or something... if you want to fun a function over all columns try: cols <-c(2:5) # set column range
df[,cols] %<>% lapply(function(x)

Comment: library(magrittr) cols <-c(2:length(df)) # set column range.... df[,cols] %<>% lapply(function(x) your_fun(x)))

Comment: Matt, your other quesiton and this one suggest you could use a little advice on how to refine your question to improve our understanding and therefore chances of getting a usable answer. [SO help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) includes some, but a [previous SO q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) does a decent job. Pay attention to the use of `dput` (with *reduced* data), and the section on minimal code.

Comment: Sorry r2evans, both nrow(m2) and nrow(m3) produce 72.

Answer (score 0):

You have "x" as an index and are using it on the RHS of a formula. The RHS of a formula is not going to be able to accept a single number at a time and do anything useful with it. The RHS should be a name of a column, and furthermore, it should be in the form of a language object. One way of doing htis would be to use as.formula, but the way I propose seemed a bit simpler to me. You apparently want to use the "x" as an index into a column, so perhaps this code would deliver what you intended:

```
for (x in names(2:ncol(m3)) ) { print(  paste( x, 
        survdiff(Surv(Overall.Survival, Status) ~ ., 
                 data = cbind( m2[ c('Overall.Survival', 'Status')] , m2[ x])

                                     )$chisq) }
```

That moves the "x" into the role of a character variable selecting a single column and then the "dot" on the RHS selects anything in data argument that is not on the LHS.

I added the `print` because things done inside an R for-loop function results do not get passed out to the global environment. The loop itself returns NULL and only by 1) assignment or 2)`print` or 3)`cat` will you see results.

This is almost certainly doing it the wrong way on a statistical basis, and I think you should be consulting a statistician for help on understanding the serious pitfalls connected with "multiple comparisons".